# for loop not working with ansible shell module

Tags: ansible

I am trying to check group ownership of all the directory named "deployments" inside path. To do this I am using for loop with find command and store all the deployments dir in variable. And then using grep I am checking whether there is any deviation. Below is my task. The problem is that the Its not working and even if group ownership is different its not detecting it.
How can i check and fix how the command i am passing in shell module is running correctly by shell module.

```
---
 - name: deployment dir group ownership check
   shell: for i in `find /{{ path }} -name deployments -type d -print`;do ls -ld $i | grep -v 'sag';done > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?
   register: find_result
   delegate_to: "{{ pub_server }}"
   changed_when: False
   ignore_errors: true
   tags:
   - deployment_dir
 - debug: var=find_result
 - name: status of the group in deployments dir
   shell: echo "Success:Deployments dir is owned by sag group in {{ path }} in server {{ pub_server }}" >> groupCheck.log
   when: find_result.stdout == "1"
   changed_when: False
   tags:
   - deployment_dir

 - name:  status of the group in deployments dir
   shell: echo "Fail:Deployments dir is NOT owned by sag group in {{ path }} in server {{ pub_server }}" >> groupCheck.log
   changed_when: False
   when: find_result.stdout == "0"
   tags:
   - deployment_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you use that shell with find?

You can `stat` the folder and then get the UID and GID for set those permissions...

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - stat:
        path: /tmp
      register: tmp
    - debug: msg="Uid {{ tmp.stat.uid }} - Guid {{ tmp.stat.gid }}"
```

Playbook run:

```
PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [stat] ********************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Uid 0 - Guid 0"
}
```

Tmp folder:

```
14:17:17 kelson@local:/# ls -la /
drwxrwxrwt  23 root   root    4096 Mai 14 14:17 tmp
```

Using that line of thinking, you can use the `find` module, register the output and use stat with your results to seek every folder permissions or set those you want...

Comment: Yes initially I was thinking to use find and file module, but since I wanted to check multiple dirs on multiple paths I lost my way and ended up with for loop and find command. Let me go back to my initial apporch to see if I can solve it this time. Thanks .